# botocore.exceptions.DataNotFoundError: Unable to load data for: sqs

Tags: python, boto3, botocore

I'm trying to run a function which purges an AWS SQS queue but I keep getting this error:

> DataNotFoundError(data_path=name) botocore.exceptions.DataNotFoundError: Unable to load data for: sqs

I have `python 3.7`, `boto3-1.21.22`, and `botocore-1.24.22` installed. I also ran `pip install --upgrade botocore`, but I'm still getting the same error.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9uOS.png)

```
sqs_client = boto3.client('sqs', AWS_DEFAULT_REGION, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

def purge_queue(queue_url): 
    try:
        response = sqs_client.purge_queue(QueueUrl=queue_url)
    except ClientError as e:
        logger.exception("Unexpected exception! %s", e)
        raise
    else:
        return response
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please do not provide textual information in the form of an image.  Copy and paste the text itself into your question, and format it properly using either the `""` or `{}` tools in the question editor's toolbar.  Also, please format any code you include in your question as such using the `{}` tool in the editor.  I took the liberty of fixing your code formatting for you.

Comment: I have a suspicion that it is your URL that is to blame, especially given the extra characters at the end of the error message, a detail that you left out of your description.  Please share the value of `queue_url` with us.  If you feel it's private, replace irrelevant parts of it, like letters or numbers, with other values.  Do as little replacement as you can.

Comment: Use keyword args when constructing a client e.g. region_name=AWS_DEFAULT_REGION. Do this for region and credentials. You can see this in the docs for [client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.client).

Comment: @jarmod has a very good point.  The way you're providing your parameters to `boto3.client()` could be your problem.  You want to do this instead:  `boto3.client('sqs', region_name=AWS_DEFAULT_REGION, aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)`.

Comment: @snowball are you now able to accept answers?

Comment: @jarmod  yes, your suggestion worked. The issue has been resolved.

Comment: I'm referring to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), specifically bullet point 2. This also helps others to know the question has been answered, otherwise it's still open.

Comment: Bumping in comments to encourage OP to accept the answer, if now able to do so.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is not initializing the boto3 SQS client [correctly](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.client).

It requires keyword arguments for everything except the service name, for example:

```
import boto3

sqs_client = boto3.client(
    "sqs",
    region_name=AWS_DEFAULT_REGION,
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
)
```

The `DataNotFoundError` exception is very misleading but is indeed caused by your failure to provide keyword arguments correctly.

You could also potentially supply the boto3.client positional arguments correctly but that would mean you have to supply all of: service_name, region_name, api_version, use_ssl, verify, endpoint_url, aws_access_key_id, and aws_secret_access_key. That's not ideal which is why supplying keywords arguments is better in most cases.

### Deeper Dive

The botocore code attempts to load a JSON service definition for the named service ("sqs" in your case) which it would typically find in `data/sqs/2012-11-05/service-2.json` but the code is mishandling the non-kwargs parameters that you are passing.

Specifically, the botocore code is inferring that the `api_version`, which is the 3rd positional parameter, is actually your supplied AWS access key, and is then failing to load the service definition from `data/sqs/your-access-key/service-2.json`. The code thinks you are telling it to use an API version of "your-access-key" (whatever AKIA... value you actually supplied here).

This also explains why you chose to obfuscate the error message in your post. The error message actually contained your AWS access key instead of the SQS API version number, because of the earlier mixup.

This unusual series of events is what triggers the `DataNotFoundError` exception because, indeed, botocore cannot load the service definition data (because it has calculated an incorrect path for it).

### Unrelated

Note: you generally don't need to explicitly indicate region and credentials at all if they are available via IAM role or local AWS credentials profiles or in supported environment variables. See [Credentials](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html).

Comment: This is only a valid answer if the OP confirms that this was the only problem.  I'm skeptical given that the error messages doesn't complain about AWS credentials nor does it suggest that the parameters that the OP is mis-providing (the 3rd and 4th positional parameters) being wrong is the issue either.  You yourself suggest that the params might not be needed.  They could be innocuous. Pointing out a fix for something secondary to the stated problem is not an answer to the question.  This is why I chose to provide the example of an alternative in the comments.

Comment: @CryptoFool I have added more substantiation of the root cause of the DataNotFoundError. I did verify this fix earlier which is why I wrote the answer. Correcting the supplied arguments fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you for fixing my code format and your suggestions @CryptoFool. It worked after adding the keyword arguments like this: boto3.client('sqs', region_name=AWS_DEFAULT_REGION, aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY) Thank you jarmod, I dont know why it wont let me tag you.